# Galaxy S3 mini only boots to recovery - how can I fix it?

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I was installing CyanogenMod when something went wrong and now my phone will only boot to recovery mode. I had made a backup but it somehow got deleted, I don't know why that happened. My computer doesn't recognize my phone when I connect it.

My phone is the Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini and I used ClockworkMod recovery. What can I do now, to fix my phone?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Can you please edit your question? It is very hard to understand what your issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not in trouble, you can go ahead and follow this link, follow the directions, and get the stock rom back on the phone.  Would probably avoid rooting the phone again if I were you.

[Flash Stock Rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2429169)

Requirements:

- Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini GT-I8190 ( N / L / T )
- USB Data Cable
- Windows Laptop / Desktop
- Odin3 v3.07
- Stock Rom ( Main / Mirror )
- Stock Recovery ( CWM / Odin )

[1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2429169) Install Recovery:

CWM =

- Copy File onto sdcard
- Place sdcard into Phone
- Boot phone to Recovery Mode ( Hold Vol Up + Home + Power )
- Click Install Zip from sdcard
- Find downloaded file on sdcard
- Click Install this Zip
- Wait till completed install
- Click Reboot Device

Odin =

( DO NOT LOAD PIT FILE IN THIS METHODS )

- Extract Zip Folder's
- Boot up Odin
- Ensure that the RE-PARTITION is unchecked, only the AUTO-REBOOT and F.RESET TIME are both remained checked.
- Place Phone into Download Mode ( Hold Vol Down + Home + Power ).
- Plug Phone into Laptop / Computer via USB
- Wait till get Connection Sign.
- Press PDA and select downloaded recovery ( .tar file )
- Click START
- Wait till get a PASS.
- Boot up Phone

[2] Install Rom onto Phone

Single Package =

( DO NOT LOAD PIT FILE IN THIS METHODS )

- Extract Zip Folder's
- Boot up Odin
- Ensure that the RE-PARTITION is unchecked, only the AUTO-REBOOT and F.RESET TIME are both remained checked.
- Place Phone into Download Mode ( Hold Vol Down + Home + Power ).
- Plug Phone into Laptop / Computer via USB
- Wait till get Connection Sign.
- Press PDA and select downloaded Rom ( .tar file ).
- Click START
- Wait till get a PASS.
- Boot up Phone

Multi File Package =

( DO NOT LOAD PIT FILE IN THIS METHODS )

- Extract Zip Folder's
- Boot up Odin
- Ensure that the RE-PARTITION is unchecked, only the AUTO-REBOOT and F.RESET TIME are both remained checked. Image 1
- Place Phone into Download Mode ( Hold Vol Down + Home + Power ).
- Plug Phone into Laptop / Computer via USB
- Wait till get Connection Sign.
- Press PDA and select the .tar file associated with a name CODE after the build number example ' CODE_I9300xxxxx_xxxxx_.tar '
- Press CSC and select the .tar file associated with a name ‘CSC’ after the build number example ' CSC_XXX_I9300xxxxx_xxxxx_.tar '
- Press PHONE and select the .tar file associated with a name ‘MODEM’ after the build number example ' MODEM_I9300xxxxx_xxxxx_.tar '

Image 5

- Click START
- Wait till get a PASS.
- Boot up Phone

Comment: Can I use any custom ROM instead of stock ROM ?